# Javers need a Retention policy for Audit Data

Tags: java, performance, javers

Any cleanup utilities/methods to remove "old" audit data in Javers to improve performance?
Also facing performance issues for complex nested Objects.
uses Javers 5.10.5 in SpringBoot application with Hibernate and Postgres 11 as Database.

**We use javers as a versioning tool for Entities.
"CommitId" taken as "eTag" value in conditional HTTP header response.**

Sample code as below:

`final Shadow<Object> shadow = javers.findShadowsAndStream(QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(instanceId, entityClass).limit(1).build()).findFirst().orElse(null); if (shadow !=null) {String eTag = shadow.getCommitId().toString();}`

Follow up on [Javers production best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972894/javers-production-best-practices#), it would be better Javers have a retention policy based on time OR snapshot version

Comment: and where is your question?

Comment: My question is, Could you provide any javers utilities/methods to clean up the jv_snaphot, jv_commit tables either by snapshot version or by DateTime.. data accrued here is considerably large. It reduces performance. Have you got my concern ?

Comment: Your issue seems legit, think about contribution